# How to run Bitcoin client in Server mode

Tags: bitcoind, solo-mining

How can I run a Bitcoin Client in a server mode. Can someone provide step-by-step directions on how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: What does "server mode" mean? Are you referring to the RPC server?

Comment: Yes, I mean RPC server.

Answer (score 1):

`bitcoind` by default runs with the RPC server enabled. `bitcoin-qt` has it off by default, but it can be enabled by adding the `-server` command line argument.

Comment: Where do you add -server. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: You add it on the command line; where that goes specifically depends on the operating system and the way you start it. One possibility is opening a shell, and then typing "bitcoin-qt -server" or "./bitcoin-qt -server" or "bitcoin-qt.exe -server". If you have a UI with an icon to click to start it, there is usually a way to edit the command line it uses too.

Comment: Thank you Pieter for your reply. I tried and bitcoin-qt.exe -server worked :)   Can I ask another quick off topic question. Do you know how to set up solo bitcoin mining on windows with BFGMiner? My miners are S19j pro (Asics).

Comment: That's a separate question; you should search for existing answers or ask a new question. I don't know anything about mining.